# SQL join performance operation order

Tags: sql, performance, query-optimization, performance-testing

I am trying to come up with how to order a join query to improve its performance.

Lets say we have two tables to join, to which some filters must be applied.

Is it the same to do:

```
table1_result = select * from table1 where field1 = 'A';
table2_result = select * from table2 where field1 = 'A';

result = select * from table1 as one inner join table2 as two on one.field1 = two.field1;
```

to doing this:

```
result = select * from table1 as one inner join table2 as two on one.field1 = two.field1
            where one.field1 = 'A' and two.field1 = 'A';
```

or even doing this:

```
result = select * from table1 as one inner join table2 as two on one.field1 = two.field1 and one.field1 = 'A';
```

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some common optimization techniques to improve your queries are here:

- `Index` the columns used in joining. If they are `foreign keys`, normally databases like `MySql` already index them.
- `Index` the `columns` used in `conditions` or `WHERE` clause.
- Avoid `*` and explicitly select the columns that you really need.
- The order of joining in most of the cases won't matter, because `DB-Engines` are inteligent enough to decide that.

So its better to analyze your structure of both the joining tables, have indexes in place.

And if anyone is further intrested, how changing `conditions` order can help getting the better performance. I've a detailed answer over here [mysql Slow query issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976617/mysql-slow-query-issue/41977997#41977997).

Comment: Thank you so much! I cannot index any table field. I am querying SAP database tables directly. I do not have any performance issue, but as I am designing the queries, if I can correctly query the database and have a slightly better performance would be better than not doing so. I didn’t know that DBEnginies could "reorder" the queries. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. I've update my answer and shared link of my another answer in which I've discussed the order of the conditions in detail. And yes if there are performance issues changing the order of conditions can help the query analyzers selecting a better plan.